# JLabel set Color from an int array

Tags: java, arrays, colors, jlabel

I'm trying to set a bunch of `JLabels` to colors from an int Array, but i'm not sure what would be the best way to do it.

This is what i got:

```
private JLabel[][] board = new JLabel[7][7];

private int[][] charA = {{Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE},
        {Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE},
        {Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE},
        {Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.WHITE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE},
        {Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE},
        {Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE},
        {Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE}};

public void setArray(){
    for(int row=0; row<board.length;row++){
        for(int col=0; col<board[row].length;col++){
            board[row][col].setForeground(charA[row][col]); 
            //setForeground gives error: The method setForeground(Color) in
            //the type JComponent is not applicable for the arguments (int)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what went wrong with that code

Comment: Just updated with the error... sorry

Comment: you need to create `Color [][]` array instead of `int[][]`

Comment: I need to use the int [ ] [ ]. Its for a school assignement

Comment: then i guess you should create a `int[][]`  int RGB color values and later you can do `board[row][col].setForeground(new Color(charA[row][col]))` and seems like your label array is not initialized so read about how to use RGB int color and 2D arrays